# Credit card not showing up on joint account holder's credit report

Tags: credit-card, credit-report, joint-account

My wife has practically no credit, and we're trying to build it up. About 9 months ago I opened a Kohl's store credit card, and added her as a joint cardholder. We recently went through her credit report from experian, and there is no trace of it on her report. I know it's her report because the only item reported there is our main credit card on which she also is a joint cardholder.

What should we do to make sure it shows up on her report?

Answer (score 4):

Is that a "joint cardholder" or just an additional card with her name? Most of the time you can just get an additional card with any name written on it. They don't even collect SSN. In this case it will not show up on a "joint" holder credit record.

Comment: She is a joint cardholder. When she signed up for it, she was given a choice between authorized user and joint cardholder, with the joint cardholder option supposedly reporting to the credit bureaus.

Comment: did it show up on your report from the same agency (experian)?

Comment: Yes, it shows up on my experian report. It even says "Responsibility: Joint with " my wifes name.

Comment: well, then i'll go with MrChrister's answer myself.

Answer (score 3):

Check all the bureaus with [annualcreditreport.com](https://www.annualcreditreport.com/cra/index.jsp).  Not all creditors report to all three bureaus, so while you aren't on experian, you could be on transunion or equifax.

Comment: Well, that account shows up on my experian report. It even says "Responsibility: Joint with " my wifes name. We'll have to check her others just in case.